# Systemctl starts the process and shuts it down RHEL 7

Tags: linux, systemctl

The application starts up normally when started on its own. While rebooting to invoking systemctl start rads it starts the application and then shuts it down.  Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

The systemctl startup file is in `/etc/systemd/system` and in the `/lib/systemd/system` directory.

Defined the following file in `/etc/systemd/system` directory for startup and shutdown.

```
[Unit]
Description=rads Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=rmkd01d
Group=rol_mkd_linux_devtest
Type=simple
ExecStart=/product/mkt_data/reuters/scripts/start_rads_AD
ExecStop=/product/mkt_data/reuters/scripts/stop_all
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Can you please provide some logging information e.g. from journalctl?

Comment: Here is the output for the journalctl -r command. Sorry abt the delay.

Comment: sorry cannot upload log files for now due to rules. Close the ticket. Regards

Comment: I was able to fix the issue. on the systemd file the "type=simple".  change of "type=forking" fixed the issue

Comment: Then please go ahead and answer your own question, that way everyone can instantly see it.